# In what situation the .NDF files are created?

Tags: sql-server, datafile

I'm not a db administrator but from a quick search I found .NDF files are secondary data files.
I'm curious to know under what conditions the .NDF files are generated ?
If it is generated, how we can know which data base is behind it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a database with a datafile(PRIMARY) in a filegroup(PRIMARY) which stores metadata as well as user data. When you reach the [maximum size](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.105).aspx) of the datafile(depended on underlying Operating System) then you need to add an extra file which is know as secondary data file. According to the reference, datafile can grow up to 16TB, so for normal sized database this situation may no arise. So it's optional to have any secondary datafiles.

However, these can be used to spread data across multiple disks by putting each file on a different disk drive.

> I'm curious to know under what conditions the .NDF files are generated ?

When you add extra datafiles on a database.

> If it is generated, how we can know which data base is behind it ?

It is added on **A DATABASE**. So you need to know database first in order to add the secondary data files. If you know that database then you can know the it's datafiles.

More details and useful links are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707403/what-are-ndf-files)

Comment: About twelve NDF files are generated and the name is tempdb1.ndf, tempdb2.ndf etc and having tempdb.mdf and tempdb.ldf. Is there anyway to know which db in the server causing this generation. I tried to 'attach', and receiving 'using by another process' error.

Comment: As their name's suggest, these belongs to [tempdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database)

Comment: @JSapkota - any idea why? There are 8 of them on my system, all 142 606 336 bytes. Why is there not just a single tempdb.mdf file?